# Why there is no 4-day job? Why everyone must work 5 or 6 days?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, internship

In my crazy country, adult must work 5 or 6(Saturday) days per week.
Start at 8 or 9 A.M. and finish in 6 P.M., with additional(they say this is default, which is very laughable) 20-30 hour/month overwork.

If I have enough money to start a company, I would definitely make a 4-day job offer. I'll make 2 teams; Mon-Thu and Tue-Fri.

4-day jobs have many good points; for example,

> - Many people who looking for a job can get one
> - If people can get 3 day/week, they can go to short trip or something, result to use money to many services
> - Government can earn more tax income

I'm unemployment. I'm looking for a job, but NO ONE didn't offer me 4-day plan.

So the question is, why there is no "4-day per week" jobs?
Why people must work 5 or 6 days until they die?

I think this destiny is sad. I also want to do other things, like hobbies, project with my friends, etc.

Comment: Related questions: "Why am I earning so low amount of money" and "Why there is unemployment"

Comment: which country are you in?

Comment: Voting to close because the answers you are calling for are of a speculative, opinion-oriented nature and not likely actionable.

Comment: As someone currently working in China, I can probably assume it's either China or Singapore. Singapore is notoriously bad for always having overtime and six-day weeks; it's a culture of everyone-doing-it-so-I-can't-but-not-do-it-too-if-I-want-this-job. I work 9:30 to 6:30 (though getting off at 6:30 is a dream. I generally get off at 7:30) currently in China.

Comment: I've seen a few companies that have every other Friday off (IT @ Federal Reserve Bank for one)

Comment: As noted by one of the answers, in the U.S. there are jobs where the workers get off Fridays. However, they work 10 hour days Monday-Friday.  Also, there are jobs where the workers put in 80 hours over 9 workdays to get every other Friday off. Unfortunately, the real answer to this lies in societal expectations and employers desire to limit costs and is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: I once knew a guy who worked 4 days *every* week, and normal hours. He had an agreement with his manager to do this. When he started this schedule, his salary was only 80% of what it was when he was working 5 days a week (which is fair, since the employer was getting about 80% of the work he used to get). I guess anyone can work 4 days a week if: 1. their employer is OK with it 2. They're OK with making less money.

Answer (score 3):

It's not impossible to get a 4 day a week job, but it's not very common.  There are a number of reasons for this:

- People tend to find themselves doing the same amount of work, for 80% of the money.  For some this is good, but for many it just adds pressure.
- It can add cost to the employer.  Most people aren't just paid for hours worked, there can be a significant cost to the employer for each worker, both in terms of benefits, but also possibly taxes etc.
- It can create significant risk, if a project is under time pressures, and the employee is due to be off the next day, what happens?  It can be a difficult thing to hand off to the alternate day worker.
- It can also be a delay to getting things done.  if a project is 20 days in estimate, that's 4 weeks on a 5 day week, but 5 on a 4 day, which may be a big issue if a deadline needs to be hit.

In the UK, especially in the public sector, you get jobs which are "job share", ie where 2 people make up one job.  Having known people who have done this it requires considerable organisation between them, often negating the benefits of doing it in the first place.

There are also jobs that allow "compressed weeks", so 9/10 hours over 3/4 days and this can work well as long as the company is doing it widespread (i.e. everyone has the chance to do it, it's not a "perk").  Usually though you have to start on a normal 5 day week, until you show ability so the job may be advertised as 5 day.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is probably because it's hard enough to get decent people to work for you in the first place, having to get even more people just because they want more free time is even tougher and in the long run more expensive for the employer.

> Government can earn more tax income

Because the company has to pay more money, finding a company that's ready to do that is rare to find.

> Why there is no 4-day job?

There are jobs that provide flexibility as such but they are rare to find. There is an alternative though, in a way, it's called freelancing. Unfortunately you're on your own there but it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

There are jobs out there with a 4-day work week.   I had a friend in a Product Manager role at a previous company who worked four 10-hour days per week.

There are even jobs out there with a 3-day work week.  Early in my career, I worked at a large insurance company as a server room manager, and my shift was three 12-hour days, 2:00 PM to 2:00 AM.

That's not to say that these jobs are easy to find.   They do exist, but as others have mentioned, they're uncommon.  If a 4-day work week is the most important thing to you, you may need to cast a broader net, e.g. look regionally or nationally instead of in your city.

Comment: 12 hour shifts can be hard on a person. Not everyone is willing or *able* to do it. I think OP wants a 9-5 x 4 shift.

Comment: Agreed.  It seemed like a great opportunity but grew old quickly.